# Generalized UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am using Swift 2.0 and I have bunch of viewcontrollers with quite similar functionality:

- Each of them is backed by an array
- Each item of this array is mapped to a `UITableViewCell`
- There is a delete functionality to delete a `UITableViewCell` and an object
- There is a new empty row to add a new object
- Each of controllers defines 5-6 methods which do exactly the same thing (just with a different backing array)

They are all similar enough for me to want to create a generalized `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` which I can instantiate in each view controller and pass only viewcontroller specific info like

- An array with the data
- `UITableViewCell` id
- etc.

I am fighting with it for couple of days. I was able to get quite generalized class which can handle most of the case. I am trying to push it forward to handle couple of additional cases.

However, the biggest problem for me was ability to pass somehow an array to this generalized which could be modified inside of this generalized class (to delete and insert new objects).

The problem is swift way of passing an array (creating a copy of it). I asked question about it [Storing a reference to array in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486043/storing-a-reference-to-array-in-swift) However, I feel I didn't get enough flexibility to generalize it.

Have anybody seen an approach to solve this generalization? Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using an NSArray object instead of the array struct of swift?

Answer (score 2):

I would have created a super class that has all the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods that you need to implement. Then I would have made overridable methods in the super class that you override in your subclasses. The super class invokes these methods when it needs to get the data etc from the delegate methods.

Example of methods that the subclass overrides from the super class.

```
// Backing array class
class MyObject {}


// Base Controller
class BaseController: UIViewController {

    // Overrideable methods for subclasses providing data.
    func backingArray() -> [MyObject] {
        return [MyObject]()
    }

    func cellId() -> String {
        return ""
    }
}

extension BaseController: UITableViewDelegate {
    // Use the methods in the same way used in the example in the data source extension.
}

extension BaseController : UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Use data from the backingArray() here.

        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return backingArray().count
    }
}


// Sub classes
class FirstSubController : BaseController {

    override func backingArray() -> [MyObject] {
        return [MyObject]()
    }

    override func cellId() -> String {
        return "AnotherCellId"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why Don't you create a viewController itself that follows `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols?

Simply create a class

```
class UVC : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var arr : [MyObject] = []
    var tableView!

    func deleteRow(i : Int){
       arr.removeAtIndex(i)
       tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func addRow(i : Int, obj : MyObject){
       arr.insert(obj, atIndex: i)
       tableView.reloadData()
    }         

    override func viewDidAppear(){
       // Initialize tableView.
    }


    ..cellForRowAtIndexPath... {
       cell.text = arr[indexPath.row]
    }

    ..numberOfRowsInSection... {
       return arr.count
    }

    ... Other Regular functions for Both Delegates/Source
}
```